# VBA Macro script to save a word document created via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know what VBA script i should write to save a word document which was created from a VBA excel script?

Here is my script so far but i would like to add a step to save the produced word document into a certain directory with the naming convention referencing a single cell in my excel sheet

```
Sub Export_to_word()

'Export Return

    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wd As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

    wdApp.Visible = True

    Sheets("PM Performance Return").Select
    Range("M1:P200").Select
    Selection.Copy

    wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    wd.SaveAs Filename:="Investment Return Period Data", FileFormat:=wdformatdocm
    WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

End Sub
```

I have added a picture for your reference:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
wd.SaveAs Filename:=Worksheets("Data").Range("B2").Value & "Investment Return Period Data", FileFormat:=wdformatdocm
```

In the above statement folder path is at cell B2 of sheet "Data". You may change it as per your scenario. Also make sure the folder path ends with "\" e.g. C:\mukul.varshney\Delete\

Comment: Thanks Mukul. After applying this code when i step through the macro i get Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

Comment: did u provide the folder path at B2 ? Or did u change the sheet name from "Data" to the one you have with the folder path ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Mukul. I did have the actual directory in cell B2. I tried it again and now it works. Much appreciated!

Comment: If the answer works for you, please mark it as answered. This will help others too